# Vert.x Http latency between two services

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I am developing a micro-services based system with asynchronous calls.

A client wants to use the system synchronously. Instead of syncing my entire flow, I came up with the following idea:

I wrote another service that acts as a gateway. It holds the `RoutingContext` in memory, invokes the asynchronous *HTTP* service, and once the async flow has finished (notified by an Event), I return the response using `routingContext.status(200).end()`.

Now, On load of about 20 events per seconds, I get every once in a latency issue when the new service forwards the HTTP call.

Here down some details concerning my environment:

- I run on *AWS*, M5 machines. (No cluster for now - testing)
- *Vert.x* async Http client to forward HTTP.
- No event loop blocks (set it to appear on 100ms).

Can the fact that I hold the `routingContext` in the memory do harm?

Comment: It shouldn't. Could you please share the parts of code where you define your routing context and where you send HTTP requests?